# Cant show text with if in .NET core

Tags: c#, .net, text

I have a Boolean in `item.estado` and i want to show "Pendiente" if it's true and "Terminado" if it's false, but this doesn't work.

````
                    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        <h4 class="mb-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id_consulta)</h4>
                        <small class="text-muted">@{if(item.estado){Html.DisplayText("Pendiente");} else {Html.DisplayText("Terminado");}}</small>
                    </div>
                    <p class="mb-2">Nombre solicitud: @Html.DisplayFor(modelIte)</p>
                </a>```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: I solved it, the problem was the html.DisplayText() , i solved it using <text><\text>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using `<text><\text>` instead of  `html.DisplayText()`

`<small class="text-muted">@{if(item.estado){<text>Pendiente</text>;} else {<text>Terminado</text>;}}</small>`